# Using BASH, selecting row and column [CUT command?]

Tags: bash

```
1   A   18  -180
2   B   19  -180
3   C   20  -150
50  D   21  -100
128 E   22  -130
10  F   23  -0
10  G   23  -0
```

In the above file, I can easily print out the column using cat command.

```
cat /file_directory | cut -d' ' -f3
```

In that case, the output would be the third column.

But,  What I want to do is something different. For example, I wanna pick the element depending on the row element.

So if I pick B from the second row, the printout would be  `[row associated "B" in the second column ][column =3] = [2][3].` which is only 19, not anything else. HOW TO DO IT?

Comment: First of all, you *can't* easily print the third column using `cut` and blank separators, because the number of blanks between columns isn't constant. And secondly, I don't understand what you're trying to do – what's an "element", as opposed to a "row element"? What's your expected output, and how do you specify that you've picked "B"?

Comment: `cat` isn't doing anything interesting here; `cut` does all the work, and can do so without `cat`: `cut -d ' ' -f3 /file_directory`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `awk`:

```
$ awk '$2 == "B" {print $3}' file.txt
19
```

`awk` splits each row into fields (by default using arbitrary whitespace a the field delimiters). Each statement has two parts: a pattern to select a line, and an action to take on a selected line. In the above, we check if the 2nd column (`$2`) has the value `"B"`; for each line for which that is true, we print the value in the 3rd column.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/sh

cat sofile+.txt | tr -s ' ' > sofile1+.txt
mv sofile1+.txt sofile+.txt

cat > edcommands+.sh << EOF
/B/
EOF

line=$(ed -s sofile+.txt < edcommands+.txt)
echo ${line} | cut -d' ' -f2,3
rm ./edcommands+.txt
```

Sofile+.txt is what contains your data.

You might also need to install ed for this, since it isn't in most distributions by default any more, sadly.